# How to get the name of an instance of Tempfile in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, temporary-files

When creating a Tempfile in ruby, it takes the `basename` you pass it, and then it appends a random string to the end.

**From the docs:** http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html

```
file = Tempfile.new('hello')
file.path  # => something like: "/tmp/hello2843-8392-92849382--0"
```

You can see it starts with `hello` and then adds `2843-8392-92849382--0`. Though this ending will change every time you create an instance.

This makes it difficult (at least for me) to lookup in the directory its saved in.

**Question:**

Is there any method (like `file.fullName`) that could be run on the instance to just get the `hello2843-8392-92849382--0`, in order to look it up in the directory where its saved?

**Thoughts:**

You could take the `path` and parse it but that seems excessive.

Comment: `file.path.split('/').last` seems excessive?

Comment: @mlovic Considering there's a function for extracting this, yes, that is excessive. It's also potentially going to give the wrong answer since on some platforms `/` can be in a filename.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I hadn't thought about that, you're right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically you're asking for:

```
File.basename(file.path)
```

There's rarely a reason to need that exposed as a method, but if you want you could subclass `Tempfile` to add it in:

```
class SuperTempfile < Tempfile
  def basename
    File.basename(path)
  end
end
```